# jquery .toggle(): is it possible to hide div with text?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to make a div with text disappear with jquery animation when I button is clicked. Nothing happens but no errors appear in chrome's javascript console. So I don't know what I did wrong.

```js
$(function() {
     $('#myb').click(function(event) {
      alert("I'm hit");
      $(this).parent('div.module').find('div.body').toggle(1);
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module">
     <div class="caption">
      <span>Module Caption</span>
      <!-- <img src="?" /> -->
      <div class="pic"></div>
      <button type="button" id="myb">show</button>
     </div>
     <div class="body">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
      Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse
      nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo.
      Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum
      sed neque vehicula rhoncus. Nam faucibus pharetra nisi.
      Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante
      ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
      cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `.parents()` with paramenter `div.module:first` for `.parent()`

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myb').click(function(event) {
    alert("I'm hit");
    $(this).parents("div.module:first").find("div.body").toggle(1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="module">
  <div class="caption">
    <span>Module Caption</span>
    <!-- <img src="?" /> -->
    <div class="pic"></div>
    <button type="button" id="myb">show</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula rhoncus.
    Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It turned out every answer here worked if I changed from jquery 1.2.1 to 1.10.1 I think it was. closest() either didn't exist or just won't work with earlier versions. Anyway, You were the first to post a solution that worked with 1.2.1 so I'll give it to you

Answer (score 2):

`.parent()` gets the immediate parent of all the children specified. In your case, it gets the parent of `$("#myb")`, which is `<div class="caption">`.

Specifying `.parent("div.module")` is the equivalent of searching the `<div class="caption">` for `div.module`. Naturally, no result is found, jQuery fails silently and nothing is hidden.

Since what you actually want is `div.module`, which is the parent of `div.caption`, you should do the following:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('div.body').toggle(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest('div.module')` instead of `parent()`

> the parent() method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these
>   elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the
>   matching elements.

```
$(function() {
      $('#myb').click(function(event) {
        alert("I'm hit");
        $(this).closest('div.module').find('div.body').toggle();
      });
    });
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myb').click(function(event) {
    alert("I'm hit");
    $(this).closest('div.module').find('div.body').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.module {
  border: solid;
  border-color: #FCAA45;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  width: 300px;
}
.body {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
.caption {
  margin: 10px;
  border-width: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
}
.pic {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #AAFFAA;
  border-width: 10px;
  background-color: #6A33FA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="module">
  <div class="caption">
    <span>Module Caption</span>
    <!-- <img src="?" /> -->
    <div class="pic"></div>
    <button type="button" id="myb">show</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam eget enim id neque aliquet porttitor. Suspendisse nisl enim, nonummy ac, nonummy ut, dignissim ac, justo. Aenean imperdiet semper nibh. Vivamus ligula. In in ipsum sed neque vehicula rhoncus.
    Nam faucibus pharetra nisi. Integer at metus. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin quis eros at metus pretium elementum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).parent('div.caption').siblings('div.body').toggle();
```